# Firebase Storage : downloading an access protected image by using http url path and custom access token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am facing issue in downloading an access protected image by url and custom access token.

Authentication Error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
   }
}
```

**IS THERE SOME CONFIGURATION I AM MISSING??**

Http url I am using to access the image having custom token as query parameter:

```
https://myfirebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myfirebasestorage-my_proj_id.appspot.com/o/images%2FIMG_4138.JPG?alt=media&token=TOKEN_GOT_USING_CREATE_CUSTOM_TOKEN_SIGN_IN
```

My storage rule :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/myfirebasestorage-my_proj_id.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null; 
    }
  }
}
```

The custom token is generated in java application as below :

```
  public static String createCustomToken(String userId, Map<String, Object> additionalClaims) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(FIREBASE_ACCESS_FILE)).build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    Task<String> customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims);
    return customToken.getResult().toString();
  }
```

I am able to verify the authenticity of the same token in java application using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken) and the log output is as below :

```
    VerifiedToken=>uid: user_id_1,
email: bhaarat@new.mail,
additionalClaims: {
  "aud": "myfirebasestorage-<my_proj_id>",
  "auth_time": 1480609782,
  "email": "bhaarat@new.mail",
  "email_verified": false,
  "exp": 1480621773,
  "iat": 1480618173,
  "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/myfirebasestorage-my_proj_id",
  "sub": "user_id_1",
  "circleId": "circle_id_1",
  "memberId": "user_id_1",
  "user_id": "user_id_1",
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {

    },
    "sign_in_provider": "custom”
  }
}
```

After signing-in with this custom token from Web Client code, I can see the correct response as below

```
{
  "uid": "user_id_1",
  "displayName": null,
  "photoURL": null,
  "email": null,
  "emailVerified": false,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "providerData": [],
  "apiKey": "API_KEY",
  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain": "myfirebasestorage-<my_proj_id>.firebaseapp.com",
  "stsTokenManager": {
    "apiKey": "API_KEY",
    "refreshToken": "REFRESH_TOKEN_FROM_FIREBASE",
    "accessToken": "ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_FIREBASE",
    "expirationTime": 1480621773681
  },
  "redirectEventId": null
}
```

**NOTE : I am able to access the nodes in firebase database using the same custom token as below.**

```
https://myfirebasestorage-my_proj_id.firebaseio.com/games/basic_info.json?orderBy=%22owner_id%22&limitToFirst=30&auth=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_FIREBASE
```

My Database Rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that the `?token=<UUID>` that `Storage` uses is not the same as the `?auth=<Firebase Auth JWT or Database Secret>` that the `Realtime Database` uses (hence their different names).

Storage provides an unguessable download URL of the format `https://myfirebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<BUCKET>/o/<OBJECT>?alt=media&token=<UNGUESSABLE_UUID>` which is designed to be shared with users who don't use Firebase Authentication (imagine sharing photos with your family/friends but you don't want to make them download an app to do it).

If you want to have downloads protected by Storage security rules, you'll need to use the native Android methods of `getBytes()`, `getStream`, `getFile()`, etc. [per the docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

Comment: I thought the token is also applicable for Firebase Storage and not just Firebase Database as mentioned on this page under heading "User private" or "Group private". Please have a look.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security

I understand that storage provide an unguessable download URL which you can also retrieve directly from firebase console -> object attributes -> "download url". The problem is as soon as someone know the download url, there is no such thing as user based access protection : anyone can view the contents and hence there is no way to secure it

Comment: My use case is as below =>
I want to share my video with you as long as you are in my friend group. Once you leave my friend group, I will not like to share anything with you and restrict the contents only to other friends in the same group. 
But In this case even if you are no more part of my friend group and since you have already got the video url you can continue accessing that video.

Answer (score -1):

you can try setting rules for all request

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```